# After I clear a large number of Snapshots (approximately 1500), FreeNAS 9.3 Web GUI displays "An error occurred." After two days

Tags: nginx, snapshot, truenas, graphical-user-interface

My FreeNAS 9.3 Web GUI crushed after I clear a large number of Snapshots (approximately 1500)

And now, It only displays these words:

```
An error occurred.
Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable.
Please try again later.
If you are the system administrator of this resource then you should check the error log for details.
Faithfully yours, nginx.
```

I tried run "# service nginx restart" command, but it didn't use.

---

Other informations following:

※ Use "cat /var/log/nginx-error.log" command:
(My FreeNAS Web URL is http://192.168.168.168/)

```
2015/07/20 09:59:24 [error] 57959#0: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.168.200, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9042", host: "192.168.168.168"
2015/07/20 09:59:25 [error] 57959#0: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.168.200, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9042", host: "192.168.168.168", referrer: "http://192.168.168.168/"
2015/07/20 09:59:32 [error] 57959#0: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.168.200, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9042", host: "192.168.168.168"
2015/07/20 09:59:33 [error] 57959#0: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.168.200, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9042", host: "192.168.168.168", referrer: "http://192.168.168.168/"
```

Thank you very much!

---

2015/07/20 Add:
In the `/var/log/messages`, it tag the "Error" only following:

```
Jul 20 09:37:00 freenas manage.py: [freenasOS.Configuration:505] Unable to load http://update.freenas.org/FreeNAS/trains.txt: <urlopen error [Errno 8] hostname nor servname provided, or not known>
Jul 20 09:37:00 freenas kernel: <118>Jul 20 09:37:00 freenas manage.py: [freenasOS.Configuration:505] Unable to load http://update.freenas.org/FreeNAS/trains.txt: <urlopen error [Errno 8] hostname nor servname provided, or not known>
Jul 20 09:37:04 freenas nmbd[78370]: [2015/07/20 09:37:04.251526,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd_packets.c:1174(process_lanman_packet)
Jul 20 09:37:04 freenas nmbd[78370]:   process_lanman_packet: Discarding datagram from IP 192.168.168.160. Source name FREENAS<00> is one of our names !
Jul 20 09:37:04 freenas kernel: <118>Jul 20 09:37:04 freenas nmbd[78370]: [2015/07/20 09:37:04.251526,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd_packets.c:1174(process_lanman_packet)
Jul 20 09:37:04 freenas kernel: <118>Jul 20 09:37:04 freenas nmbd[78370]:   process_lanman_packet: Discarding datagram from IP 192.168.168.160. Source name FREENAS<00> is one of our names !
Jul 20 09:37:12 freenas manage.py: [freenasOS.Configuration:505] Unable to load http://update.freenas.org/FreeNAS/trains.txt: <urlopen error [Errno 8] hostname nor servname provided, or not known>
Jul 20 09:37:12 freenas kernel: <118>Jul 20 09:37:12 freenas manage.py: [freenasOS.Configuration:505] Unable to load http://update.freenas.org/FreeNAS/trains.txt: <urlopen error [Errno 8] hostname nor servname provided, or not known>
```

PS: My FreeNAS host cannot touch the Internet.

---

2015/07/20 Add:
I found following page to solve my problem:
[FreeNAS Web UI not responding](https://serverfault.com/questions/646794/freenas-web-ui-not-responding)

and I use the following steps to solve this question:

Step 1: 
Run `ps auxwww | grep freenas` command

Step 2: 
Find the result like `root        3118   0.0  0.4 557616 140848 ??  I    25Jun15     45:41.21 /usr/local/bin/python -R /usr/local/www/freenasUI/manage.py runfcgi method=threaded host=127.0.0.1 port=9042 pidfile=/var/run/django.pid (python2.7)`

In this case, the PID is 3118

Step 3: 
Run `kill -15 3118` to kill process

Step 4: 
Run `ps auxwww | grep freenas` to check process 3118 is already killed.
If not, Run `kill -9 3118` to force kill this process.

Step 5: 
Run `service django start` to restart django process. Done!

---

But, I still don't know how the website crush after I delete many snapshots...

Thanks!

Comment: You need to show the logs of FreeNAS, because the issue is there.

Comment: What would you say "/var/log/messages" this log file? thx!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how FreeNAS does its logging.